# How to retrieve a customer's payment history with Stripe?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

For my react app, I am using the [Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions) object to handle purchases in Stripe, and I am using a Customer object if the user is logged in. I'm having trouble figuring if I'm supposed to use the [Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents), [Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges), or [Balance Transaction](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions) object to retrieve a customer's payment history (provided the customer id).

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You would use the List all PaymentIntents API to get a customer's payment history:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list#list_payment_intents-customer

By default this will return the last 10 payments that the customer made. But, you can increase that number to 100:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list#list_payment_intents-limit

If you want to list more than the last 100 payments you would need to use the auto-pagination feature provided by Stripe's libraries:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto

Depending on what information you need to display in your app you could also use the [List Charges API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list). But that resource is being phased out in favor of PaymentIntents so I would look to use PaymentIntents first. The Balance Transactions API is mainly useful for displaying changes to a given Stripe account's balance rather than a given customer's payment history (i.e., tracking all payments, transfers, payouts and refunds on the account as a whole).